# Loop over an object and assign a value to an array of objects if certain conditions are met - vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

Say I have an object like so (there could be a lot of items in here);

```
myObject:{
 item1: {
  visible: true;
 },
 item2: {
  visible: true;
 },
 item3: {
  visible: false;
 },
}
```

and then an array of objects like so (there could be a lot of items in here);

```
var objs = [ 
    { name: 'item1', visible: false },
    { name: 'item2', visible: false },
    { name: 'item3', visible: false }
];
```

How do I iterate through the object and assign the value of visible to the array **only when the names match** -  **If Item1 in the object is `visible: false`, then item1 in the array must reflect that**

Comment: Don't loop through the object.  Loop through the array.  Find the element by the objs.name, and set the objs.visible equal to the found element's sub-key visible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient way is to loop through the array as you only iterate the array once.

```js
const myObject = {
 item1: {
  visible: true
 },
 item2: {
  visible: true
 },
 item3: {
  visible: false
 }
};


var objs = [ 
    { name: 'item1', visible: false },
    { name: 'item2', visible: false },
    { name: 'item3', visible: false }
];

objs.forEach(obj => {
  const property = myObject[obj.name];
  if (property) {
    obj.visible = property.visible;
  }
});


console.log(objs);
```

Comment: a `forEach` would be better, since your not modifying `obj` or at least don't want to

Answer (score 3):

Loop over your `myObject`, and find the object within `objs` using [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), then set the value of that found object:

```
for (let o in myObject) {
  let obj = objs.find(i => i.name == o)
  if(!obj) continue
  obj.visible = myObject[o].visible
}
```

Here is a working example:

```js
const myObject = {
 item1: {
  visible: true
 },
 item2: {
  visible: true
 },
 item3: {
  visible: false
 }
}

var objs = [ 
    { name: 'item1', visible: false },
    { name: 'item2', visible: false },
    { name: 'item3', visible: false }
]

for (let o in myObject) {
  let obj = objs.find(i => i.name == o)
  if(!obj) continue
  obj.visible = myObject[o].visible
}

console.log(objs)
```

Comment: Sorry I could be reading this wrong, but aren't you changing the value in the object?  Not the array?

Comment: I did it the opposite way that you wanted, see my edits this should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myObject = {
 item1: {
  visible: true
 },
 item2: {
  visible: true
 },
 item3: {
  visible: false
 }
};


var objs = [ 
    { name: 'item1', visible: false },
    { name: 'item2', visible: false },
    { name: 'item3', visible: false }
];

Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myObject).forEach(propertyName => {
  let obj = objs.find(o => o.name === propertyName);
  if (obj) {
    obj.visible = myObject[propertyName].visible;
  }
});

console.log(objs);
```